# How to get the original from address in a forwarded message in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

i want to know how to get the original sender of a forewarded mail using google app engine
mail_message.original object?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs : If you use Python you have to analyze the message :

original is the complete message, including data not exposed by the other fields such as email headers, as a Python email.message.Message.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html